# Flutter Icon Scale

Tags: flutter

i want to rescale my icon and rotate my icon until it's scale become 0,but i can only 'set' icon's size which means size become instantly 0 without animation, tried to wrap icon with animated container, but it doesn't effect to icon, any ideas for rotating and rescaling icon by time ? my code's here below.

```
 Widget build1(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget1;

    var animatedContainer = AnimatedContainer(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        color: animSize ? Colors.greenAccent[700] : Colors.yellow,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.group,
            size: animSize ? 0:90,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              animSize = true;
            });
          },
        ));

    widget1 = animatedContainer;
    return widget1;
  }
```

Comment: You should use `AnimationController`. `AnimatedContainer` won't work here as it animates only its own properties: width, height etc.

Comment: can you give me more details please, i know how to use animationController but don't know how to use it for icon.

Comment: okay solved it.